# How to create a EditText box which opens a dialog on click?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create an `EditView` box which is being used as a button that you click. It opens a dialog with checkboxes you choose and then it inserts the chosen options into the textview with comma separated. For example the dialog has the following options:

```
Please select options:
[] Option1
[X] Option2
[] Option3
[X] Option4
```

Then after you exit the dialog you will have in the `EditText` box:

```
Option2,Option4
```

I have created the `EditText`:

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text_data"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Add data"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

And a currently empty dialog xml called `dialog_adding_data.xml`. In the Java file I have:

```
        EditText dataEditText = findViewById(R.id.text_data);
        dataEditText.setClickable(true);
        dataEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddData.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_adding_data,null);
                // Now what?
            }
        });
```

But how do I continue? How should I display the data in the dialog and get it when clicked ok? Also, when I click the EditText, it still opens the keyword so I can add the text (which I don't want). It should be blocked somehow. Only the dialog should "add" text to the `EditText` box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data from your alert dialog and set the text of the edittext, something like

```
        dataEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddData.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_adding_data,null);
                // Now what?

                mBuilder.setView(mView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // Change the following to the view in your dialog that has the user data
                   EditText editText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.EDIT_TEXT_ID);

                   String value = editText.getText().toString();
                   dataEditText.setText(value);
                })
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try that. How do I block the `EditText` box from opening the keyboard and inserting the data manully?

Comment: Also tried it, and it didn't work. You even don't have `mView` in the inner method.

Comment: if you dont want to type any thing inside the Edittext then simply use a TextView that would be a good option.